# React.js Component not being created

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects I wanted to display in a table.
I have the following code

```
class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: this.props.data
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table>
          {this.state.data.map(row => {
            console.log(row);
            <Test/>
          })}
      </table>
    );
  }
}

class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("7");
  }

  render() {
    return;
  }
}
```

The *console.log()* in the *Table* prints out all my data correctly, however, the *console.log()* in my *Test* constructor never prints.
Why is the *Test* not being created?

---

My proper rows is below:

```
class Rows extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: this.props.rowData
    };

    console.log("2");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{this.state.data.paymentFrom}</td>
        <td>{this.state.data.paymentTo}</td>
        <td>{this.state.data.paymentPeriod}</td>
        <td>{this.state.data.paymentAmount}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Test component to be rendered correctly, you must to return the component, if it never return on the function body, will never gonna print.

Try this way:

```
class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: this.props.data
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table>
          {this.state.data.map(row => {
            console.log(row);

            return (<Test/>)
          })}
      </table>
    );
  }
}

class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("7");
  }

  render() {
    return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return <Test/>` for it to initiate and render.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, that whole section is inside a return already.

Comment: This answer is correct, but if you aren't seeing logging, then you aren't passing data to your Table as props. You don't show us that code.

Comment: you are correct, I was testing the wrong version. Why is an extra return needed?

Comment: The extra return is not for `React` but for the `.map` method. That's how `.map` works in js. You have to return from with `.map()` method. If you don't, it won't be part of the new array constructed by `.map`.